# rdd.map() does not call the specified function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset of 3 items. I call a function on each item using `map()` but the function is never called.

```
object MyProgram {

  val events = Seq("A","B","C")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("MyApp")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val eventsDS = events.toDS()
    System.out.println("Before")
    val tempDS = eventsDS.rdd.map(x => doSomething(x))
    System.out.println("After")

  }

  def doSomething(event: String) : Unit = {
    System.out.println("Do Something!")
  }
}
```

Output:

> Before
>
> After

Comment: In your code you not called any [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) try this one `eventsDS.rdd.collect.map(x => doSomething(x))`

Comment: @Yogesh Oh of course, it makes sense! Yes, now it's working. Please write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is lazily evaluated, you need to call an [`action`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) like `foreach` to perform the computation:

```scala
eventsDS.foreach(doSomething _)
```

Comment: Agreed! my point was more to highlight that `map` doesn't get evaluated - Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Additionally, since `doSomething()` will be run on the executors, you shouldn't expect to see output on the driver node.